# Копирование или клонирование объекта

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
$r2 = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($r); $i++) {//$r это массив объектов Room  
   $rt = new Room();  
   $rt = $r[$i]; 
   array_push($r2, $rt);  
}
echo "\n ".$r[0]->x; //допустим 42  
$r2[0]->x = 13;  
echo "\n ".$r[0]->x; //13!
```

Как сделать так чтобы изменять копию объектов и не менялись значения в оригинале? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: $rt = clone $r[$i]; и убрать строку $rt = new Room();  - она не используется

Comment: Вы создали объект Room в переменной `$rt`, а на следующей уже строке в эту же переменную пытаетесь положить что то из массива $r под ключом $i, что немного странно) Скорее всего вам достаточно перед тем как ложить объект в массив сделать так: `array_push($r2, clone($rt));`

Comment: не один из предложенных на данный момент решений не работает

Comment: @WaldeMar не верю! Значит что то не отражено в вашем примере..

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример немного запутан. Чтобы работать с копией объекта, нужно создать его с помощью ключевого слова `clone`.

```
class Room
{
    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->x = $value;
    }

    public $x;
}

$r1 = new Room(10);
$r2 = $r1;
echo $r1->x . PHP_EOL; // 10
$r2->x = 20;
echo $r1->x . PHP_EOL; // 20
```

Как видим, изменив $r2, изменился объект $r1, т.к. объекты в PHP по умолчанию передаются по ссылке.

А теперь сравните с:

```
$r1 = new Room(10);
$r2 = clone($r1);
echo $r1->x . PHP_EOL; // 10
$r2->x = 20;
echo $r1->x . PHP_EOL; // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что каждый элемент массива `$r` это довольно большой объект, в нем есть другие объекты, и массивы. В итоге я клонировал (воспользовавшись советами данными мне здесь) столько тот внутренний объект, что мне был нужен. Наверное для клонирования больших объектов нужно перегружать функцию `__clone` внутри требуемых классов. Не имею понятия как это сделать.

Comment: хмм. Ну да, если в объекте были _ссылки_ ну др. объекты (т.е. по сути если в объекте были др. объекты), то после клонирования они и остались ссылками. И при модификации по ссылке  меняется и исходный объект (ведь объекты передаются по ссылке). Внутри `__clone` по идее надо переопределить необходимые свойства, т.е. применить `clone()` для внутренних объектов : $this->obj = clone($this->obj);